# how to add my current SSL certificate to any new subdomain?

Tags: ssl, dns, certbot

I have a domain like https://domain.zone this domain has SSL I am trying to use this certificate for all my subdomains using `certbot` command but it doesn't work this my command :

```
certbot -d domain.zone,*.doman.zone,www.domain.zone --expand
```

this not worked for me, I have too many subdomains and users crate their own subdomains I can't add all subdomains manually, so how to solve this for all new subdomains?

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But certificates are there to validate an identity, that is the name of a website. Hence a certificate has to be created with either the list of names it covers (up to 100 in most cases) or a wildcard that matches all labels below a given zone. You can have everything in one certificate or multiple ones. If your users create subdomains, your system has then to automate the certificate issuance. PS: saying "it doesn't work" without details is not the ideal way to phrase a question

Comment: @PatrickMevzek So, how to make all subdomains to support SSL using wildcard?

Comment: You create a certificate for `*.example.com` that will match all names directly below `example.com`

Comment: this not helped me I can't use `*.example.com` in `certbot`

Comment: "I can't use *.example.com in certbot" You certainly CAN. And you are not explaining why you can't. Go in documentation at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html grep for wildcard and just find: "Some CAs (such as Let’s Encrypt) require that domain validation for wildcard domains must be done through modifications to DNS records which means that the dns-01 challenge type must be used" Problem solved. But your question remains both vague and off topic on this forum.